# Cell phone receiving text messages between an acquaintance and his girlfriend

Tags: android, mobile, sms

An acquaintance was staying with us a short time ago and I let him use my cell phone to text his girlfriend and listen to music. A week ago he acquired a cell phone of his own. Completely different make/model than mine and using a different service provider. I have just noticed that his text conversations between him and his girlfriend are appearing on my cell phone. Yet they both are using different phones, different phone numbers, and different services. I know he downloaded some music apps on my phone. Did he download something else? My phone is an android

Comment: what messaging app did he use on your phone?

Comment: Two text apps; "Messaging" 4.4.4-20180228.152609.2 4933, and "Phone/Messaging Service" 4.4.4-20180228.152609.2 4933   (same number!)

Comment: Ok, that appears to be the built-in SMS messaging apps on Android.

Comment: I'd simply look at the settings for the girlfriend's number to see if texts are mirrored/forwarded to the friend's new number

Comment: Is it possible that they accidentally created a group chat with your phone number on it?